# Why not snackbar icons in Material?

Tags: material-design, guidelines

I was reading through the Material Design guidelines and noticed this restriction on the snackbar usage: ["Don’t place icons in snackbars."](https://material.io/components/snackbars/snackbars.html#anatomy-figure-caption-2)

Why not? What would be the rationale for that?

Comment: Because could easily look like a button?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that at multiple parts:

### When to use - Table

**Component:** Snackbar
**Priority:** Low priority

**Component:** Banner
**Priority:** Prominent, medium priority

**Component:** Dialog
**Priority:** Highest priority

[**Source:** MD Usage -> When to use](https://material.io/components/dialogs#usage)

## Possible Explanation:

As it is writte, a snack bar has low priority. MD also tells you to use **Alerts** if you need to use a icon. This means that Icons are prioritized higher than *low* on the Material Design Guidelines.

An **Alert** is a sub display of **Dialog** which has a priority of *Highest priority* compared to the *Low priority* of the **snackbar**.

This is what MD says about **Alerts**:
"*Alert dialogs interrupt users with urgent information, details, or actions.*"

Snackbars are not supposed to "interrupt" users but just quickly inform them. Any visual stimulant, such as Icons, could interrupt the user. So the most logical explanation is, that Icons are having a priority of atleast medium, as snackbars have a low priority. Here is a full part about icons [on material design](https://material.io/design/iconography/) you should dive into for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is about user interaction with Snackbars. When a Snackbar *(or toast!)* appears on screen, I just scan it quickly to check everything went well. Not reading the content of the Snackbar.
Using icons needs more attention to understand the message. As you can see **"Alert"** is recommended on Google Material guideline.